# How to set up Trigger Condition that depends on nested property?

Tags: .net, wpf, triggers, styles

Can I set up a trigger that have something like this?

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuSelector" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="SelectedItem.Tag" Value="MyTag">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyTagContextMenu}"><!-- change context menu depending on selected item --></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <!-- Other triggers depending on the value of the SelectedItem's Tag -->
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I want to be able to change the ContextMenu of the treeview depending on the Tag of the selected item. However the above code doesn't compile because it seems that nested property like `Property="SelectedItem.Tag"` is not allowed. Any idea?

Comment: check with <Trigger Property="SelectedItem.Tag.ToString()" Value="MyTag"

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItem is of type object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx but tag is a property on type FrameworkElement. To specify the SelectedItem type try using Property="(FrameworkElement.SelectedItem).Tag"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx see section on type-qualified